# How to start android app as service after booting

Tags: java, android

I am trying to start up an android app as background service after initial run. At first run, the app should start as normal android app, then after, that it should be a background service which still runs even after booting. I wrote the following code. The service class is verified as standalone android app. But this app is not running as expected. No error code, but when debug, service class is not working.

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.tulga.nar.mytrack">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Initial one time running activity class:

```
package com.tulga.nar.mytrack;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.view.View;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

}
public void starterHandler(View v)
{
 new MyBroadcastReceiver();
}
}
```

Initial one time running activity class's xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tulga.nar.mytrack.MainActivity">

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/starter"
    android:text="start service"
    android:onClick="starterHandler"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Broadcast receiver class. It is called from MainActivity after start service button is clicked. It is supposed to start background MyService class.

```
package com.tulga.nar.mytrack;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent aIntent) {

    // This is where you start your service
    aContext.startService(new Intent(aContext, MyService.class));
}
}
```

This is background MyService class. The class is verified and works as standalone app. But here, code execution is not reaching to here when debug.

```
package com.tulga.nar.mytrack;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

 /**
 * Created by Home on 8/27/2017.
 */
  public class MyService extends AppCompatActivity implements 
  LocationListener 
 {
  private class SendDeviceDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String data = "";

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url=new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
       "application/json");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.connect();

            DataOutputStream wr = new 
            DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            wr.writeBytes(params[1]);

            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
            while (inputStreamData != -1) {
                char current = (char) inputStreamData;
                inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                data += current;
            }
        } //catch (Exception e) {

        //e.printStackTrace();
        //}
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("TAG", result); // this is expecting a response code to be 
 sent from your server upon receiving the POST data
    }
 }

 public  static final int RequestPermissionCode  = 1 ;
 static public double myLong=151;
 static public double myLat=-34;
 static public String _id=null;
 static public String _rev=null;

 Button buttonEnable, buttonGet ;
 TextView textViewLongitude, textViewLatitude ;
 Context context;
Intent intent1 ;
Location location;
LocationManager locationManager ;
boolean GpsStatus = false ;
Criteria criteria ;
String Holder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EnableRuntimePermission();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    criteria = new Criteria();

    Holder = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    CheckGpsStatus();
   JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
    try {
        postData.put("_id",String.valueOf("9876543210"));
        postData.put("Lat", 
   String.valueOf(String.valueOf(MyService.myLat)));
        postData.put("Long", 
    String.valueOf(String.valueOf(MyService.myLong)));
        postData.put("_rev",String.valueOf("1-
    62076042d87cacd2711268d4a396129b"));
        new SendDeviceDetails().execute("my-server-name/mydatabase", 
    postData.toString());

    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    textViewLongitude.setText("Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    textViewLatitude.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude());
    myLong=location.getLongitude();
    myLat=location.getLatitude();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

public void CheckGpsStatus(){

    locationManager = 
 (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    GpsStatus = 
 locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

}

public void EnableRuntimePermission(){

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MyService.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
    {

        Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission 
    allows us to Access GPS in app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MyService.this,new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 
  RequestPermissionCode);

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int RC, String per[], int[] PResult) 
{

    switch (RC) {

        case RequestPermissionCode:

            if (PResult.length > 0 && PResult[0] == 
   PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"Permission Granted, Now your 
  application can access GPS.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"Permission Canceled, Now your 
   application cannot access GPS.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: The `<receiver>` element has to go between the `<application>` tags, just like the `<activity>`. You also need a `<service>` element for `MyService`, in the same place.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant in your case, but the user must manually start the app before any broadcast receivers will be called.  It must be manually started again after being force closed.

Comment: At first time user must manually start my app, and after that only service will stay even after rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't regest your serice in mainifest,and your broadcastReceiver is not at the right place.It should like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tulga.nar.mytrack">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".service.MyService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="write your action name" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you help me by clarifying service declaration part? What I should write on service android:name and action android: name. I implemented my service class in MyService class. I am trying to create a background service which send gps info to a server.